# Finding Cross-ranking matches between multiple columns in R

Tags: r, match

I have a sampling problem where I'm looking to search through columns of data for the highest ranked matches (which correspond to other set of data). Some matches are already ruled out:
-9 because it was the first selection (col 1 values)
-2 because it was highest ranked in set 9 (col 2 values)
-7 because it was highest ranked between cols 1 & 2 (col 3 values)

**For example, the highest ranked match between columns 1,2,3 should be 1 because it has rank [2,7,2] across the three columns, which is the lowest sum. This new rank result would append to the 10x3 matrix to make it a 10X4 matrix, and a fifth match would then be sought.**

```
       [,1]  [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    2    9    9
 [2,]    1   10    1
 [3,]    4    6    3
 [4,]    5    8    2
 [5,]    7    7    4
 [6,]    8    3    6
 [7,]   10    1   10
 [8,]    3    5    5
 [9,]    6    4    8
 [10,]    9    2    7
```

The goal is to do this for much larger data sets (say 500 rows) and creating a subset of about 20 values, so something besides visual inspection is needed! The list of numbers in each column is the same length and includes the same values, just in a unique order for each column.

Comment: could you be a bit more specific with this question.  It seems an interesting problem, but I'm having trouble making out exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the set of numbers is identical in all columns?